# two date columns to produce new series with selected dates

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with two date columns, each row corresponding to a disjoint interval of time. I am trying to produce a series which contains as an index all dates from the minimum date to the maximum date from the original columns and has a value 1 if it is a date within one of the original time intervals.

```
pd.DataFrame({"A":[pd.Timestamp("2017-1-1"), pd.Timestamp("2017-2-1")], 
             "B": [pd.Timestamp("2017-1-3"), pd.Timestamp("2017-2-3")]})

id  A           B
0   2017-01-01  2017-01-03
1   2017-02-01  2017-02-03
```

To this,

```
pd.DataFrame({"A":[pd.Timestamp("2017-1-1"),pd.Timestamp("2017-1-2"),pd.Timestamp("2017-1-3"),
                   pd.Timestamp("2017-2-1"),pd.Timestamp("2017-2-2"),pd.Timestamp("2017-2-3")], 
             "B": [1,1,1,1,1,1]})

id  A           B
0   2017-01-01  1
1   2017-01-02  1
2   2017-01-03  1
3   2017-02-01  1
4   2017-02-02  1
5   2017-02-03  1
```

Comment: Do you have an example of your data or what you have tried so far?

Comment: I can provide an example but I feel it to be very self explanatory. I have tried many approaches using loops but I feel as if there might be a smart way to go around it using Pandas built in functions.

Comment: much easier for us to try it ourselves if you provide code to rapidly reproduce this dataframe

Comment: Hope that helps, not sure how to show output

Answer (score 1):

Not really pythonic but I think it solves your issue:

```py
In [1]:
from datetime import date, timedelta
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[pd.Timestamp("2017-1-1"), pd.Timestamp("2017-2-1")], 
             "B": [pd.Timestamp("2017-1-3"), pd.Timestamp("2017-2-3")]})

dates_list = []
for k in range(len(df)):
    sdate = df.iloc[k, 0]   # start date
    edate = df.iloc[k, 1]   # end date

    delta = edate - sdate       # as timedelta

    for i in range(delta.days + 1):
        day = sdate + timedelta(days=i)
        dates_list.append(day)

final = pd.DataFrame(data=dates_list, columns=['A'])
final['B'] = 1
final

Out [1]:
        A       B
0   2017-01-01  1
1   2017-01-02  1
2   2017-01-03  1
3   2017-02-01  1
4   2017-02-02  1
5   2017-02-03  1
```